# check namespace for a node

Tags: xslt

How to check if namespace exists or not for an element ?

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for a complete solution. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to check if namespace exists or
>   not for an element ?

This question isn't quite clear. In XML (+namespaces) every node has at least two namespaces -- with reserved prefixes "xml" and "xmlns")

**I interpret the question to mean**:

> How to check if a node is *in* a
>   namespace.

**Solution**:

```
not(namespace-uri() = "")
```

this expression is `true()` exactly when the current node is in a namespace and `false()` otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

A namespace always exists - it might be the [default](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml-names/#defaulting) one, but it will exist.

Comment: but how to check using <xsl:if> condition ?

Comment: @Madhu CM - My point is that _there is_ **always** a namespace. Why check for something that always exists?

Comment: <xsl:if test="local-name()='ABC' and namespace-uri()='http://xyz.com'">t</xsl:if>  cannot be done in this way ?

Comment: @Madhu CM - Was your actual question _How_ to test against a _known_ namespace? You didn't ask that.

Comment: sorry for that . Can you do that way or is there any way

Comment: @Medhu CM - can you please explain _exactly_ what you are trying to do? I still don't know what that is. Please edit your question and add that to it, instead of in comments to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Properly speaking, a QName is a tuple (namespace URI, local name, prefix).

For node types other than elements and attributes, namespace URI and prefix are empty.

For an element under a no null (or empty) default namespace URI, only prefix is empty.

All attributes with empty prefix have empty namespace URI.

Each item can be selected with these expressions:

```
namespace-uri($node)

local-name($node)

substring-before(name($node),':')
```